# PayPal credentials not working on Laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal

I am trying to use [this library to include Paypal in my Laravel](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal) application.

After installing it and giving the credentials, I get this error:

```
  "L_ERRORCODE0" => "10002"
  "L_SHORTMESSAGE0" => "Security error"
  "L_LONGMESSAGE0" => "Security header is not valid"
  "L_SEVERITYCODE0" => "Error"
```

So it seems that my credentials are not correct.

Here is the credentials for the sandbox:

```
    'username'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME', ''),
    'password'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD', ''),
    'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET', ''),
    'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
    'app_id'      => '*****',
```

I have been looking for the credentials for hours now. Anyone knows exactly where each are?

I found "username" and "password" for sandbox somewhere, but there are no secrets or certificates, and I have found "username" ,"Client ID" and "Secret" but the aforementioned "username" does not even match the previous "username".

I am completely lost. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What it sounds like you're trying to pull is the NVP creds and you have REST creds instead. You can pull the your api nvp creds found in your developer.paypal.com account; check these shots --> http://prntscr.com/grstzh, http://prntscr.com/grsu6s, http://prntscr.com/grsuau. Hope this helps.